# trying to establish "current" class on sidebar link

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I have an "About Us" section of my website. I am trying to attach current classes based upon the url.  When you click on the about us section of the website, it takes you to a channel entry whose url_title is "pastors-welcome", and while on that page, the "about-us" template group index page is displayed, so segment_1 is "about-us" and segment_2 is blank.  If you navigate the pages within the about-us template group, the current class displays correctly because segment_2 == url_title, but when segment_2 is blank, obviously no class will be applied.  I basically need a conditional that says, if segment_2 == url_title, OR (segment_1 == "about-us" AND segment_2 == "blank") then apply this class.  I'm not sure if that's a great explanation, but here's my code:

```
{embed="embeds/html_header" page_title="{exp:channel:entries channel="about_us"}{title}" {/exp:channel:entries}}

<ul class="categories">
        <a href="{path=about-us}"><h2 class="section-header">About Us</h2></a>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="about_us" dynamic="no" {gv_param_disable_all}}
        <li><a{if segment_2 == url_title} class="current"{/if} href="{homepage}/about-us/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I figured this one out:

```
{if segment_2 == url_title || url_title =="pastors-welcome" && segment_2 == ""}
```